# Unable to export object from another js file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to have the getCurrentSongData function to return the songdata object that is passed in from the scraper, but I keep getting this output:

```
******************TESTING****************
c:\Users\(PATH TO PROJECT FOLDER)\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:82
        throw err;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'artist' of undefined
    at getCurrentSongData 
...
```

Here's the section of my routes.js file that requires my scraper.

```
function getCurrentSongData(un) {

    var scraper = require('./scrape');

    console.log("******************TESTING****************");
    console.log("testfunct: " + scraper(un).artist);

         return scraper(un);

}
```

[Here's the scraper](http://pastebin.com/qUhcX7Tx)

Answer (score 0):

You're making an *asynchronous* request in `scrape.js` so you need to use the callback that returns the fetched song data, otherwise you get `undefined` because the `module.exports` function isn't returning anything.

```
function getCurrentSongData(un) {
  var scraper = require('./scrape');
  scraper(un, dataLoaded);
}

function dataLoaded(songData) {
  console.log(songData.artist);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this to my code. Does the function dataLoaded go in my routes.js file or in the scraper?

Comment: So if I'm trying to load the result from the scraper to the routes.js file I would put this in routes.js? It dosn't seem to be working.

I also have a route with:

res.render('nowplaying.ejs', { songdata: getCurrentSongData(lastfm) });